# Cannot do inclusion on field studentId in exclusion projection error when getting document count with mongoose virtuals

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a syste using mongoose/mongodb.

So I have this schema

```
const TutorStudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    tutorId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user', required: true },
    studentId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user', required: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    oObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
  }
)
```

And I created a virtual

```
TutorStudentSchema.virtual('count', {
  ref: "practiceSet",
  localField: "studentId",
  foreignField: "studentId",
  match: {submitted: true, reviewed: false},
  justOne: false,
  count: true
})
```

The referenced "practiceSet" schema looks like this:

```
const TutorStudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    ...
    studentId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user', required: true },
    ...
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    oObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
  }
)
```

When I populate with the count virtual with "count: false" it works fine by fetching all documents that match in an array, but when is set"count: true" I expect to get the count of the matched documents but I get this error:

```
Cannot do inclusion on field studentId in exclusion projection
```

I've tried removing "justOne: false", "match", and both of them at the same time. But the issue seems to be coming from setting count to true. is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: when you add count the result just be count number,

Comment: @mohammadNaimi that's the expected result. But it ends up throwing an error rather than returning the count number